# How can I get the 3 most frequently-appearing companions here

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Table 1 - `tblCompanion`:

```
companionid | companionname    | who played
--------------------------------------------------- 
1           | River Song       | Alex Kingston
2           | Rory Williams    | Arthur Darvill
3           | Wilfred Mott     | Bernard Cribbins
4           | Rose Tyler       | Billie Piper
5           | Adam Mitchell    | Bruno Langley
6           | Donna Noble      | Catherine Tate
7           | Jackson Lake     | David Morrissey
8           | Sarah Jane Smith | Elisabeth Sladen
.           | .                | .
.           | .                | .
.           | .                | .
```

Table 2 - `tblEpisodeCompanion`:

```
Episodecompanionid | EpisodeId | companionid
---------------------------------------------
1                  | 1         | 4
2                  | 2         | 4
3                  | 3         | 4
4                  | 4         | 4
5                  | 5         | 4
6                  | 6         | 4
7                  | 7         | 4
8                  | 8         | 6
9                  | 9         | 6
10                 | 10        | 6
11                 | 11        | 1
12                 | 12        | 1
13                 | 13        | 2
.                  | .         | .
.                  | .         | .
.                  | .         | .
```

From these two tables I want these results:

```
No | companianName | Episodes
-----------------------------
1  | Amy Pond      | 33
2  | Rose Tyler    | 32
3  | Rory Williams | 25
```

I'm been trying this for hours but can't get the result set like above, 
please explain to me how to solve this.

Comment: What have you tried?  This seems like a pretty basic `JOIN` and `GROUP BY` query.

Answer (score 0):

This query should do that for you:

```
SELECT TOP 3 
    tblCompanion.companionname, 
    Count(*) AS Episodes
FROM tblEpisodeCompanion 
    INNER JOIN tblCompanion 
        ON tblEpisodeCompanion.companionid = tblCompanion.companionid
GROUP BY tblCompanion.companionname
ORDER BY Count(*) DESC
```